# How to make onclick work between div tags?

Tags: jsf, xhtml, onclick, primefaces, facebook-like

I want to call a bean function in *onclick* between *div* tag, but as far as I know one cannot simply call nonscript function in this situation. Actually I am putting an *facebook like button* as:

```
<div class="fb-like" data-href="#{someBean.getSomeUrl()}" data-send="false" 
    data-layout="button_count" data-width="100" data-show-faces="false"
            onclick="#{someBean.saveLikeCount()}">
</div>
```

and I need this kind of *onclick* operation in order to update and save like count to my database (Facebook automatically increases that number but holds it to itself, so I need to get the count and save it to my database when somebody clicked that like button). Is there a way out ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What kind of framework do you use, Java Server Pages?

Comment: I am using jsf and primefaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `onclick` method will never be fired due to fact that Facebook Like Button actually will be loaded in `iframe` placed in that element, and event will not propagate to your document... And this way you will never know what user did like or unlike.

You can however listen to `edge.create`/`edge.remove` events (of Facebook JS-SDK) to be able to know whenever someone liked/un-liked

```
FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function(url) {
  // Like was created for `url`
});

FB.Event.subscribe('edge.remove', function(url) {
  // Like was removed for `url`
});
```

Comment: Thanks for reponse and I am sorry if it is a dummy question but I have tried the example here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/ by writing it between script tag, but it didn't work? Do I have to add something else too, or should it work when I just clicked the like button?

Comment: You may look into live [sample](http://jsfiddle.net/juicyscripter/eyWx8/3/) to get the clue ;)

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked. Although I had done the same thing before, it worked now. The difference was that I had put it outside of the body tag but now it is between the body tag. I don't know whether it is relevant or I just correct one unimportant mistake by copy-paste :) But thanks a lot.